# How to get the last digits of 2 power

Tags: java, biginteger

I’m working on a problem where its demanded to get the last 100 digits of 2^1001. The solution must be in java and without using BigInteger, only with int or Long. For the moment I think to create a class that handle 100 digits. So my question is, if there is another way the handle the overflow using int or long to get a number with 100 digits.

Thanks for all.

Comment: I think that this problem should be solved with an analytic approach instead that explicitly calculating 2^1001.

Comment: Related: http://projecteuler.net/problem=16

Comment: [Dear Alpha, what is 2^1001 modulo 10^100?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+2%5E1001+modulo+10%5E100). ;^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do it (coding wise) is to create an array of 100 integers and then have a function which starts from the ones place and doubles every digit. Make sure to take the modulus of 10 and carry over 1s if needed. For the 100th digit, simply eliminate the carry over. Do it 1001 times and you're done.

Comment: thank you for the answer, using a table of integer its faster than a spécific class.

Comment: You can use `long` storing 9 digits at a time.  I suggest 9 so you can square the result to calculate powers of 2 more efficiently. i.e. you can calculate n^512 with n^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2

Answer (score 3):

EDITED: I was off by a couple powers of 10 in my modulo operator (oops)

The last 100 digits of 2^1001 is the number 2^1001 (mod 10^100).

Note that 2^1001 (mod 10^100) = 2*(2^1000(mod 10^100)) (mod 10^100).

Look into properties of modulo: http://www.math.okstate.edu/~wrightd/crypt/lecnotes/node17.html

This is 99% math problem, 1% programming problem. :)

With this approach, though, you wouldn't be able to use just an integer, as 10^100 won't fit in an int or long.

However, you could use this to find, say, the last 10 digits of 2^1001, then use a separate routine to find the next 10 digits, etc, where each routine uses this feature...